# How to do git pull request from intellij idea?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have a private project repo on github owned by a company. The repo on github has branches master and dev. At some point in the past I cloned the dev repo. After that I made quite a few changes. Now my manager requires I need to do pull request so that the team can review my changes. I cannot do merge with dev branch. What is the sequence of commands in intellij idea to accomplish this. If equivalent git commands can be used from the intellij idea project directory that can also help. FYI I have been using intellij idea VCS | Update project feature with Update type merge and clean working tree type stash to merge remote changes to my local ones.

Will this process create a new branch on remote repo which the team will look at to review my changes?

Answer (score 0):

So at first you need to create a branch that you will use for pull request on the GitHub. Be on a branch where you created changes and type `git checkout -b 'new branch name'` for example `git checkout -b feature/my-stuff`.
After that, you should be on your new branch with all the commits that you have committed in the previous branch and/or you can commit the other changes. Now you should rebase your branch onto *origin/dev* (or whatever the origin branch is in your case) to get all the changes from other developers `git rebase origin/dev`. Now resolve possible conflicts (if there are any). If all conflicts are resolved you can now safely push your branch by typing `git push --set-upstream origin feature/my-stuff`. 
Now you can go to GitHub and create pull request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, git itself has no concept of "pull request". This is a feature of services that are built on top of git such as GitHub. You can go to the private GitHub repo in your browser to create a pull request through the web interface. You first need to push your local branch to the GitHub repo so that it is available there. Then you can create the Pull Request in the GitHub web interface. I recommend learning how to do this first before looking into integrations with your IDE. Your team lead or another team member should give you guidance about how to do this. Each team has slightly different procedures, so you should ask them for some mentorship in how they want it done.